# how to get object value in side of [http post] in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, delete-row

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Delete(string ID)
        {                    
            return View(objDB.SelectDatabyID(ID));
        }

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(Customer objCustomer)
        {           
            string result = objDB.DeleteData(objCustomer);
            ViewData["result"] = result;
            ModelState.Clear(); //clearing model
            return View();
        }
```

in this code [httppost] side not gettig value..it will be show null value in objCustomer..basically Customer is a modelclass..how to get customerid value in [httppost] side..

Comment: Share you view page code.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to pass Customer model from view check below code :

**First Method with Form Serialization :**

```js
$("#SubmitBtn").click(function () {
    $.ajax(
                   {
                       url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "ControllerName")',
                       type: "Post",
                       async: false,
                        dataType: "html",
                       contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                       data: $('form').serialize(), //here you have to pass your form name for pass all data to controller action
                     contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                       success: function (data) {
                            $('#PartialResultDivName').html(data);
                       }
                   });
 });
```

**Second Solution with without Form Serialization :**

```js
 var Customer = {
        "Name": $("#Name").val(),
        "Address": $("#Address").val()
        //Add all properties 
    };
    $.ajax(
     {
         url: '/YourControllerName/Delete/',
         type: "Post",
         async: false,
         dataType: "html",
         data: JSON.stringify(Customer),
         contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
         success: function (result) {
             //Return Result
         }
     });
```

**Cheers !!**

Comment: Please post your form's HTML and Razor code so we can you identify the problem.

Comment: pls send u r mail Id brother

Comment: @babi "no problem solved" what do you mean that Issue has not been resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can simply do this by using the form, In a view, put all your controls which has binded with the Customer  model inside the form tag including submit button. thats it

Now if you click submit, mvc will bind all the controls value to the model corresponding property and will give you as a complete model.

Ex: view code

```
 @model Mul.Models.Customer

@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.customerId)

                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.customerName)

                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>


    }
```

Same Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(Customer objCustomer)
        {           
            string result = objDB.DeleteData(objCustomer);
            ViewData["result"] = result;
            ModelState.Clear(); //clearing model
            return View();
        }
```

Note: you should put formmethod.post other you wont get it as a model.

Hope the above information was helpful.

Thanks

Karthik